# Missing whitespace between literal and alias bigquery

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have this python code:

```
def insert_actions_table(client, json, uuid):
    session_id = (json['session_id'])
    if(session_id == None):
        session_id =  '"Null"'
    timestamp = str(json['timeStamp'])
    new_category = '"' + str((json['category']).replace("-", "_")) + '"'
    action = '"' + str(json['action'].replace("-", "_")) + '"'
    new_current_url = json['current_url'].replace("-", "_")
    if(len(new_current_url) == 0):
        new_current_url = '"Null"'
    if(new_current_url[0] == '/'):
        new_current_url = new_current_url[1:]
    query_text = f"""
    INSERT `insights-30062021.em_first_try._actions` (_session_id, _timestamp, _category, _action, current_url, _uuid)
    VALUES ({session_id}, {timestamp}, {new_category}, {action}, {new_current_url}, {uuid})
    """
    query_job = client.query(query_text)

    # Wait for query job to finish.
    query_job.result()

    print(f"DML query modified {query_job.num_dml_affected_rows} rows.")
    return query_job.num_dml_affected_rows
```

But I get this error:

> google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Syntax error: Missing
> whitespace between literal and alias at [3:75]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you show the final value of the query_text variable?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar error when I tried to use insert code in bigquery.
Maybe you can try to add "" just like "{YOUR_VARIABLE}".

For example:

```
query_text = f"""
INSERT `insights-30062021.em_first_try._actions` 
(_session_id, _timestamp, _category, _action, current_url, _uuid)
VALUES ("{session_id}", "{timestamp}", "{new_category}", "{action}", "{new_current_url}", "{uuid}")
"""
```

Also, the error may happen when the types of variables not fit the schema in your bigquery table.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to change `whitespice` setting. For this, open `tslint.json` and set false whitespice setting.

```
"whitespace": [
      false,
         ...     ],
```

**Note:** Don’t forget to restart app after this changes.